# Forming a symmetric matrix counting instances of being in same cluster

Tags: python, r, matrix, cluster-analysis

I have a database that comprises cities divided into clusters for each year. In other words, I applied a community detection algorithm for different databases containing cities in different years base on modularity.
The final database (a mock example) looks like this:

```
v1 city cluster year
0 "city1"  0  2000 
1 "city2"  2. 2000
2 "city3"  1. 2000
3 "city4"  0  2000
4 "city5"  2  2000
0 "city1"  2  2001
1 "city2"  1  2001
2 "city3"  0  2001
3 "city4"  0  2001
4 "city5"  0  2001
0 "city1"  1  2002
1 "city2"  2  2002
2 "city3"  0  2002
3 "city4"  0  2002
4 "city5"  1  2002
```

Now what would like to do is counting how many times a city ends up in the same cluster as another city each year.
So in the mock example above I should end up with a 5 times 5 symmetric matrix where rows and columns are cities where each entry represent the number of times that city I and j are in the same cluster (independently of which cluster) in all years:

```
       city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
city1   .     0.    0.     1.    1
city2.  0.    .     0.     0.    1
city3.  0.    0.    .      2.    1
city4.  1.    0.    2      .     1.  
city5.  1.    1     1.     1.    .
```

I am working in python but it's fine even if the solution is in matlab or R.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, co-occurrence matrices are computed straightforwardly with `table` and `[t]crossprod`.  We can compute the matrices by year and take the sum, like so:

```r
con <- textConnection('
v1 city cluster year
0 "city1" 0 2000 
1 "city2" 2 2000
2 "city3" 1 2000
3 "city4" 0 2000
4 "city5" 2 2000
0 "city1" 2 2001
1 "city2" 1 2001
2 "city3" 0 2001
3 "city4" 0 2001
4 "city5" 0 2001
0 "city1" 1 2002
1 "city2" 2 2002
2 "city3" 0 2002
3 "city4" 0 2002
4 "city5" 1 2002
')
d <- read.table(con, header = TRUE)
close(con)

x <- with(d, Reduce(`+`, apply(table(city, cluster, year), 3L, tcrossprod, simplify = FALSE)))
x
```

```
       city
city    city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
  city1     3     0     0     1     1
  city2     0     3     0     0     1
  city3     0     0     3     2     1
  city4     1     0     2     3     1
  city5     1     1     1     1     3
```

There are threes on the diagonal because cities match themselves every year.  If you prefer, say, zeros on the diagonal, then you can add:

```r
diag(x) <- 0
```

If you don't like the redundant annotation with "city", then you can add:

```r
dimnames(x) <- unname(dimnames(x))
```

And if you want to store the result as a formally symmetric, formally sparse matrix, then you can add:

```r
library(Matrix)
x <- as(x, "CsparseMatrix")
x
```

```
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
      city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
city1     .     .     .     1     1
city2     .     .     .     .     1
city3     .     .     .     2     1
city4     1     .     2     .     1
city5     1     1     1     1     .
```

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, we may use `crossprod` with `table` - just `paste` the 'year', 'cluster' to a single string, get the `table` with `city` and apply `crossprod` on the output, then modify the `diag`onal value by assigning it to 0

```
out <- `diag<-`(crossprod(with(df1, table(paste(year, cluster), city))), 0)
```

-output

```
out
      city
city    city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
  city1     0     0     0     1     1
  city2     0     0     0     0     1
  city3     0     0     0     2     1
  city4     1     0     2     0     1
  city5     1     1     1     1     0
```

---

If we need a sparse option

```
library(Matrix)
> Matrix(out)
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
       city
city    city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
  city1     .     .     .     1     1
  city2     .     .     .     .     1
  city3     .     .     .     2     1
  city4     1     .     2     .     1
  city5     1     1     1     1     .
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), city = c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", 
"city5", "city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", "city5", "city1", 
"city2", "city3", "city4", "city5"), cluster = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L), year = c(2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```